# Emacs package "flycheck" missing after relaunch

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

Every time I exit and relaunch emacs, the `flycheck` package is missing and needs to be reinstalled manually with `package-install`.

All other packages that I have installed are working fine.

This issue appeared after I updated my packages today, which I hadn't done in a few weeks.

Right now I'm using flycheck version 0.25 (package: 20151017.122) and emacs 24.5.1 on OSX together with Spacemacs.

Comment: What's the value of the variable `package-user-dir`? You can display it's contents via `C-h v package-user-dir RET` Can you see the files being installed there?

Comment: The value is "~/.emacs.d/elpa" and in that directory there is a subdirectory "flycheck-20151017.122" after I install flycheck.